# Problem starting cake bake in console

Tags: php, console, cakephp-1.3, cakephp

I've got a fresh install of the new build of cakephp (1.3) and the bake console does not seem to be working.

I got to the folder in the console and do the usual cake bake and it doesn't seem to be working.

This is the output from the console:

```
xxxx:console yyyy$ ./cake bake
-bash: ./cake: Permission denied
```

Has something changed in the new version of cake?

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, notice that you can't run the command `./cake` from the root of your CakePHP installation directory--the item called "cake" there is a folder, and can't be executed.  The console executable is located at `[installdir]/cake/console/cake`.

When using bake, you'll want to do it from your app folder.  If you've done much work already, it might be wise to first back up the app folder.  Then, from your CakePHP installation folder, do

```
cd app
../cake/console/cake bake
```

and you should be all set.

Comment: How come in the instructions they point to the `lib/Cake/Console` path?

Answer (score 14):

Using the terminal go to the directory in where you have the cake file. I talking about the /cake/console...  once you are there run the next string

chmod 755 cake

and it's ready, the permission to execute the file is set.

Answer (score 1):

**If you're working on a Linux operating system:**

1- Make sure that both (**cake cake.bat cake.php**) have writing permissions.

To do so:

2- In your terminal, **once you are in your project directory**:

```
cd app/Console 
ls -la
```

[image: You should see the following:]

3- now run the following commands:

```
chmod -R 777 cake
chmod -R 777 cake.bat
chmod -R 777 cake.php
```

In my terminal shell, the green color assures me that I now have the desired permissions

[image: In my terminal the green color tells me that I now have the desired permissions]

4- Now you should be able to run:

```
./cake bake
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this to work? I think this could do the trick. (Running the command from your `app` directory

```
 chmod +x Console/cake
```